# Laravel eloquent join con condición

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Tengo estas tablas:

| users | role_user | roles |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
|  | user_id |  |
|  | role_id |  |

Y quiero consultar los usuarios dependiendo el rol que yo envíe como parámetro, tengo la consulta en SQL y seria la siguiente.

```
select * from authentication.role_user inner join authentication.users on authentication.role_user.user_id = users.id
inner join authentication.roles on authentication.role_user.role_id = authentication.roles.id
where authentication.role_user.role_id = 2
```

He llegado hasta este punto en mi codigo:

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
       if ($request->has('search')) {
            $users = User::email($request->input('search'))
            ->firstlastname($request->input('search'))
            ->firstname($request->input('search'))
            ->identification($request->input('search'))
            ->secondlastname($request->input('search'))
            ->secondname($request->input('search'))
            ->get();
        }else{
            $users = User::paginate($request->input('per_page'));
        }
        return $users;
    }
```

Y obtengo los usuarios, pero quiero que me devuelva los usuarios dependiendo del rol el cual yo envíe por parámetro.

Comment: Lo tenés relacionado el usuario con el rol? Si no lo tenés, deberías, para poder utilizar eloquent. [Así se hace](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Una vez lo tengas relacionado, solo filtras por `$user->rol($request->input('rol'));`

Comment: sii, muchas gracias